# How is homogeneity defined for a function of one variable?

Tags: functions, polynomials

By definition a homogeneous function is a function whose terms all have the same degree. So according to this is $ f(x) = x^2 $ a homogeneous function?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: @BlackHole *"I would like to yield a general formula for inverse of a 3×3 matrix using row operations.Isn't that obvious? Probably nobody here knows the answer. "*  First of all, no: it was not obvious, especially since you starting out asking for "the general form of RREF".  What?!?! Second, why are you re-deriving formulas that exist using less convenient methods, and then acting like it's the obvious thing to do?  Yes, it is possible, either by cleverly multiplying to make the matrix straightforwardly reducible, or by breaking it up into 6 different cases.

Comment: @BlackHole And finally, you have some nerve to ask for help, make no effort to make yourself understood, then be a jerk about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; it's homogeneous of degree 2.

"Homogeneous" is mostly used for multi-variable polynomials, since for single-variable ones, "homogeneous" is the same as "monomial". The degree-3 2-variable polynomials are linear combinations of 
$$
x^3, x^2y, xy^2, y^3
$$
such as $3x^3 - 2x^2y + 14 xy^2 + 11y^3$.